# os.getenv() returns None after setting environment variables

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am following simple tutorial which requires setting up of environment variables. I have set a few in the following way:

```
C:\Users\fsdam>set GITHUB_USERNAME=damaf

C:\Users\fsdam>set GITHUB_USERNAME
GITHUB_USERNAME=damaf
```

When I check this setting in Python, `None` is returned:

```
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.getenv('GITHUB_USERNAME'))
    None
>>>
```

I have restarted my PC but I had to set them again and still did not work. What am I dong wrong or missed?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting these variables for the current command prompt session only. This will not affect other sessions (neither current, nor launched in future) and will be gone once you close this one. If you want to set permanent  variables that will be available in any new command prompt (and visible to  Python too), you need to add it in "Environment variables" window or use `setx` command.

```
setx VARIABLE_NAME "VARIABLE_VALUE"
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx